# How can I write a vba to delete all x lables for all charts in the spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, charts, axes

I have 7 stacked column charts in one tab. I want to write a vba to remove all vertical labels on the left hand side in all charts. I thought it would be simple but it's not!

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to "delete all x labels" or "remove all vertical labels on the left hand side"?  That reads as though you are first referring to the horizontal x-axis and then to the vertical y-axis - bit confusing.  Helps if you use the Excel terminology - vertical or horizontal axis.  And remove axis, axis title or axis tick labels?

That aside...  you can loop through all chart objects in a worksheet like this:

```
Sub loopCharts()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 to ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

    'do some stuff with the chart

Next i  

End Sub
```

For example, if you want to delete the vertical axis:

```
Sub delVertAxisAllCharts()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 to ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.Axes(xlValue).Delete

Next i  

End Sub
```

If you just want to remove the horizontal tick labels:

```
Sub remHorizTickLabels()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 to ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlNone

Next i  

End Sub
```

Hope that helps...